# Parse XML with PHP; hard to find a tag

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
  <response>
    <result code="1000">
      <msg lang="en">Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <msgQ count="1" id="1139047">
      <qDate>2007-09-26T00:00:00+02:00</qDate>
      <msg lang="en">Domain transfercode</msg>
    </msgQ>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>c2265c8bcd2f46dfeb34822fdeafab2a</clTRID>
      <svTRID>20150312.53840968.486516024</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

And i'm looking to get the ID attribute in msgQ : 1139047

Here's my PHP code :

```
$msgQueue = simplexml_load_string($xmlCode); 
$ack = $msgQueue -> response -> msgQ -> attributes() -> id;
```

But doesn't work; must be pretty obvious but i'm pulling my hairs out here; what am I missing ?

Thanks

EDIT: dump of $msgQueue:

```
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  ["response"]=&gt;
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (4) {
    ["result"]=&gt;
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=&gt;
      array(1) {
        ["code"]=&gt;
        string(4) "1301"
      }
      ["msg"]=&gt;
      string(46) "Command completed successfully; ack to dequeue"
    }
    ["msgQ"]=&gt;
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
      ["@attributes"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        ["count"]=&gt;
        string(1) "1"
        ["id"]=&gt;
        string(7) "1139047"
      }
      ["qDate"]=&gt;
      string(25) "2007-09-26T00:00:00+02:00"
      ["msg"]=&gt;
      string(19) "Domain transfercode"
    }
    ["resData"]=&gt;
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
    }
    ["trID"]=&gt;
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
      ["clTRID"]=&gt;
      string(32) "4cde4d0853c39c590b0ab65915101130"
      ["svTRID"]=&gt;
      string(27) "20150312.53840982.486516205"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did `resData ` come from?

Comment: Please, show us value of $msgQueue

Comment: @JohnConde sorry was typo; so many lines open ...

Comment: It works for me! *But doesn't work;* What does that mean do you get any errors? Add error reporting at the top of your file(s) and tell us: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` if you get any

Comment: You have been given an "answer" below. Let them know why it may not be working.

Comment: The source in the question works: https://eval.in/299375

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$ack = $msgQueue -> response -> msgQ -> attributes() -> id;
```

Comment: He already said 4min ago that it was a typo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011721/parse-xml-with-php-hard-to-find-a-tag/29011842?noredirect=1#comment46268537_29011721

Comment: Why is this answer still shown as what the OP **really** had and was a typo? It no longer applies as being the solution.

Comment: OP: *"Here's my PHP code :

`$msgQueue = simplexml_load_string($xmlCode); 
$ack = $msgQueue -> response -> msgQ -> attributes() -> id;`"*

Comment: @Disco You shouldn't go passing blame thinking it was them. FYI: That's my downvote. You made a typo and didn't mark your question as an **Edit: I made a typo...**, but you chose to place it in comments instead. Plus, you didn't tell the person who gave you the answer here that they should provide a solution and edit their answer. As it stands, your question is unclear and others have even provided comments that it worked for them. So, you'll need to take it up with the person who answered here, to help provide "the solution".